# midnight commander files location on mac

Tags: macos, mc

I'm trying to find mc config files on mac. I've used macports to install it.
The `.mc` folder in home dir doesn't affect the mc behaviour - not hotlist nor others configs.

So where is the mc config files exists, and how to find them? (is there any utility to check which file was written when I press a Save Config button?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `~/.config/mc`

More infos why it is like it is: http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/index.html#introduction